# Runtime error: Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on Visual-Studio 2013 "MVC" project.

I am using a "Bootstrap-select" plug-in to search and select options in drop-down. It is a multi-select drop-down with a search functionality init.
Initially, I am using a multi-select checkbox which stores the values. But as the requirement changed I used Bootstrap plugin.

The problem is after storing the drop-down values in database, the values are not being displayed in the drop-down in "Edit-Mode". I used ViewBag property to store values in the controller. The values are being stored in the ViewBag in the controller but not being displayed (kept selected) in Front-End.

When I open the drop-down edit link, a pop-up is being displayed in the visual- studio that " Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference?"
[Pop-Up error box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIN11.jpg)

And when I click continue the page goes to browser and the drop-down doesn't display the selected values.

The code-line where error occurs is

```
$('li > a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() == pathname.toLowerCase()) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

I guess the problem lies with the occurring of pop-up.
I searched for similar answers in stack-overflow but I see any of those are not concerned with my answer.

Comment: Use `$('li > a[href]').each(function () {`

Comment: Thankyou @Tushar . But even though I changed the script in javascript file visual studio auto generates a js file(while hosting to browser) with previously coded script and the changed script doesnot gets affected in autogenerated file.What to do?